# Serious battery life impact since upgrading to 22.04

Tags: suspend, power-management, battery, 22.04, xps

Since upgrading from 21.10 to 22.04, the battery life on my XPS 9300 has dropped by 30-40%. It also started draining during sleep.

I've tried auto-cpufreq without TLP, and I've tried TLP without auto-cpufreq.

The laptop is in AHCI mode and seems to enter s2idle correctly. Deep sleep is apparently not supported by the XPS. After forcing it via grub, it would just show the Dell logo when I reopened the lid, but never actually do anything.

What has changed so much in Ubuntu 22.04 that makes battery life drain so badly?

Comment: Sure is really sleeping? Did you let the battery drown below ~10% lately? Did you see anything abnormal on system logs (`journalctl -xe`), `uname -r`? Tried older kernels? Tried live distro? Do you have a Linux optimized sleep state on BIOS? `[deep]` in `cat /sys/power/mem_sleep`?

Comment: mem_sleep holds `[s2idle] deep` instead; I tried before to force deep sleep with the grub option; however the laptop would then not wake up so I don't think that was a good idea :)

Comment: i am facing similar issues on my Acer Swift 3 (SF314-59-524M). After upgrading to kubuntu 22.04, the laptop seems to loose all of 100% battery power "overnight" while sleeping and shuts-down. Next morning it starts charging from 0% again. This happens once every 2-3 days and is very confusing. There are no specific messages in syslog to help diagnose this. cat /sys/power/mem_sleep shows [s2idle] deep. Not sure what is going on.

Comment: i have explained my problem here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1418663/kubuntu-22-04-looses-all-battery-power-over-night-even-while-in-sleep

Comment: This should NOT be an OS issue but hardware related. The drain from a battery when the system is off or sleeping ==should== only because of USB3 power-on mode (so the USB3 ports keeping power to charge a device; phone etc). Otherwise it should be going down very very slowly if it is sleeping.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced similar issues after upgrading a Lenovo Thinkpad T14 Gen1 from Ubuntu LTS 20.04 to version 22.04. After putting notebook in suspend battery drain completed within 12 hours.
The recommendations from contributor Rinzwind put me on track solving this.
The following BIOS adjustments to the default settings worked for me (including turning off settings I don't use)

- Config \ Network \ Wake on LAN : Disabled
- Config \ Network \ Lenovo Cloud Service: Off
- Config \ Network \ UEFI Wifi Network boot: Off
- Config \ USB \ Always on USB: Off
- Config \ Power \ Sleep state: Linux
  (probably the most important one)

Comment: Switching "Config \ Power \ Sleep state" to "Linux" fixed it for my ThinkPad X1. I left the other options untouched because I don't know what they meant.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be related, but I had a similar issue with my XPS on Ubuntu 22.04. My battery went from lasting 8 hours, to barely 2. Reinstalling CUDA fixed it. Check if CUDA is working correctly using `nvidia-smi`. It should tell you if the drivers are correctly working.

I hope that helps.