# Kubuntu 22.04 looses all battery power over-night even while in sleep

Tags: kubuntu, suspend, power-management, battery

This problem seems to have started after i upgraded to Kubuntu 22.04
Machine is: Acer Swift 3 (SF314-59-524M)

**The Problem**

Every night i turn off the mains supply (laptop is at 100% battery power), and when i wake up in the morning, laptop is shutted-down, because battery = 0%.

This happens randomly once every 2-3 days.
On normal days its in sleep and spends only about 8-10% power during night.

Note: I usually do not close the lid of the laptop. I just get away from my desk leaving it as is.

**System Configuration**

Here are some command outputs from this laptop.

```
$ cat /sys/power/mem_sleep
[s2idle] deep
```

what does s2idle + deep together mean ?
according to kernel docs on sleep states
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/power/states.txt

s2idle = S0 and deep = S3

Supported sleep modes as reported by dmesg:

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep -i acpi | grep supports
[    0.187564] ACPI: PM: (supports S0 S3 S4 S5)
[    0.343570] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS supports [ExtendedConfig ASPM ClockPM Segments MSI HPX-Type3]
```

I checked BIOS, there is no special "Linux" sleep or suspend mode/option.

So what is happening with the battery power and how can i fix it ?

**Inspection**

I suspected the laptop WOKE up at midnight and did something power intensive, but when i checked certain system logs it shows this:

```
$ cat /var/log/syslog | grep -E 'systemd-sleep'
Jul 13 21:19:10 acerlight-laptop systemd-sleep[27117]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...
Jul 13 22:16:48 acerlight-laptop systemd-sleep[27117]: System returned from sleep state.
Jul 13 23:29:55 acerlight-laptop systemd-sleep[39657]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...
Jul 14 07:20:05 acerlight-laptop systemd-sleep[39657]: System returned from sleep state.
Jul 14 11:25:50 acerlight-laptop systemd-sleep[5947]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...
...

$ last -x | grep shutdown
shutdown system down  5.15.0-41-generi Thu Jul 14 12:27 - 12:29  (00:02)
shutdown system down  5.15.0-39-generi Thu Jul 14 07:20 - 10:35  (03:14)
shutdown system down  5.15.0-39-generi Mon Jul 11 05:25 - 19:59 (2+14:33)
shutdown system down  5.15.0-39-generi Sat Jul  9 18:15 - 03:39  (09:23)
shutdown system down  5.15.0-39-generi Wed Jul  6 12:57 - 22:38 (2+09:40)
```

1. It can be seen that laptop slept off at 13th Jul/11:30 night and it was 100% battery since the mains supply was ON.
2. Next morning 14th July/7:20 AM it woke up (NOBODY was there).
3. The laptop shutdown at 7:20 AM right after waking up, because battery = 0%.
4. I resumed work and turned it on at 10:35 AM to see that battery = 0%.

This implies that the laptop must have lost power during SLEEP very likely.

**Battery Test**

Hence I decided to use the laptop on battery today to check if the battery has gone bad.

But the battery is giving good running-time, and looks totally fine.

**Note:**

*1. There is a USB 3.2Gen1 (blue) colored USB A port on the left side which has this "power-off charging" feature.

I have a Dell KB216 wired keyboard connected to this USB port. According to discussions on Acer forums, this port provides power to devices even when the laptop is sleeping.

So is this wired keyboard drawing power from the laptop while its sleeping and responsible for draining its battery ?

I don't think so, because when I am actually using the laptop on battery with the keyboard connected, it lasts over 5 hours with continuous usage (web browsing, document editing).

And if the keyboard indeed draws that much power, it should happen every day.

Also how much power would a wired keyboard drain.

However, the keyboard num-lock, caps-lock leds go off, when the laptop sleeps.

*2. The power adaptor remains connected to both the laptop and the wall mains socket always. Is it possible that the battery leaks power back to the mains socket due to something wrong with the power adaptor.

But again that should have happened with previous versions of Ubuntu as well, which it didn't.

Comment: Maybe check with powertop is something is either waking up or stopping it from going to deep sleep (generally an IRQ). Generally, a faulty USB device. This might also be due to internal cable connecting webcam to motherboard getting wonky and on normal days it works properly, but on other nights, the cable causes spurious interrupts on USB bus. Use powertop to disable wakeup from network, USB and sata.

Comment: "The power adaptor remains connected to both the laptop and the wall mains socket always." this reads as a hardware problem. There is NO WAY an OS can drain a notebook over night that is connected to a wall socket when it is "on" let alone when it is "off". "But again that should have happened with previous versions of Ubuntu as well, which it didn't." Nah, hardware dies due to the most impossible looking events. Installing an OS is highly unlikely but I would not say "never". Maybe you damaged a  connector. Also unlikely but not impossible ;=)

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issues when upgrading from Ubuntu 20.4 to 22.04. My laptop has one USB port with power off charging. Disabling power off charging and setting sleep state to linux in the BIOS, fixed my issues.

I have no idea why this was not a problem in 20.4.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1245358)

Answer (score 0):

https://learnubuntumate.weebly.com/draining-battery.html

sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
change the line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" in
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash mem_sleep_default=deep"
sudo update-grub
reboot
now the command : cat /sys/power/mem_sleep
should give you:
s2idle [deep]
it means you switched the suspend mode from the worst s2idle to the best deep.

Answer (score -1):

This may help someone. Its not a fix but an acceptable workaround for me anyway. I have spent the last 6 weeks searching for a fix that i could understand and apply fix. Can not find anything that explains it in enough details for a beginner. This is a workaround that is not to difficult for new users.

My system -
OS = Debian
ISO = firmware-testing-am64-netinst.iso
Followed install instructions on YouTube "Install Linux the right way" If you watch and follow instructions you should be able to install this even if your new to Linux.
Laptop = ASUS E210

Workaround (takes about 30 seconds to do these steps)
Logout of your GUI session (Don't shutdown)
Press Control + Alt + F1 keys (at the same time)
At the login prompt type your username and password and press enter.
At the dollar prompt ($) type sudo su and press enter.
Type username and password again and press enter
You are now at a root prompt (#).
Type init 0 (That is init then a space then a zero and press enter)
Your laptop will now shut down and the battery will not drain.

Steps summary

1. logout Not shutdown
2. Ctrl + Alt + F1
3. Username and password
4. Sudo su
5. Username and password
6. init 0